# What's the difference between domain.errors.hasErrors() and just domain.hasErrors()?

Tags: grails, error-handling

Can someone please explain why sometimes grails developers use `foo.errors.hasErrors()` and other times they use just `foo.hasErrors()`? Are they synonymous or is one correct while the other is not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are synonymous. See GormValidationApi.groovy. Domain.hasErrors delegates to underlying [Errors](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html) object.

Comment: https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/a1fc154088d45d83315300b7041faed354aa2c9d/grails-datastore-gorm/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/gorm/GormValidationApi.groovy#L202